# How to pull contents of a file using python and GHE API

Tags: python-3.x, github-api

I am trying to use the get contents api listed here https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents for github but I seem to be missing some of the context. I want to just pull the contents of a file using a python script in my terminal. For example, I'd like to make a request to the following url https://github.com/BrandonK-Seed/auditree-config/blob/master/controls.json and have it return every line in this file.

I've tried running the GET /repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:path but I think I am missing the code around it.

Trying to use this

```
import requests
import json

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'token xxx',
}

response = requests.get('https://api.github.com/repos/Brandon/BrandonSeedTest/contents/auditree_config', headers=headers)
if(response.ok):
    content = json.loads(request.content)
with open('./evidence.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(response.text)
```

I'd just like to return the entirety of a file in github through a simple python script. The above returns {"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.16/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents"} in the .txt file

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Python lib `requests` and get the data from the endpoints:

```
import requests
import json

request = requests.get('https://api.github.com/path')
if(request.ok):
    content = json.loads(request.content)
    # Do something with content
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I have upvoted your response as it has helped me shape the script. I am trying to run ```import requests
import json

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'token xxx',
}

response = requests.get('https://api.github.com/repos/Brandon/BrandonSeedTest/contents/auditree_config', headers=headers)
if(response.ok):
    content = json.loads(request.content)
with open('./evidence.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(response.text) ``` but it is returning not found error

Comment: @BrandonKonieczny Pasting your whole code in a comment makes it hardly readable. Edit your question and add the issues you faced with that code. Say explicitly what line threw that `not found` error

Comment: Sorry I'm unfamiliar with markdown but I've edited my initial comment.

Comment: You didn't mention what line iis throwing the `not found` error

Comment: I'm not getting an error persay, the results of the API call are giving me not found in my evidence.txt. I know the path is correct so I believe my syntax is incorrect. It runs fine, just not giving me expected results.

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct? Try opening it on your browser. If it prints a json then it's a valid endpoint, otherwise it isn't. If the path is valid, then there is probably something wrong with your authentication

Comment: My token is 100% valid, I am using it for other applications. I think I am just not understanding how to code the path. For example if I wanted to grab the contents of this public repo file (https://github.com/ravahn/FFXIV_ACT_Plugin/blob/master/Releases/FFXIV_ACT_Plugin.zip), how would I change my request? If I could get a single example I could fix mine